# Could not register the selector 'window'

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mono, interface-builder

When trying to debug this Xamarin solution, the *build* is successful, but when trying to open the app on the simulator, this message is thrown in the Application Output:

> Could not register the selector 'window' of the member 'Mobile.iOS.AppDelegateIPad.get_Window' because the selector is already registered on the member 'get_window'. (MonoTouch.RuntimeException)

The callstack then shows that we stopped somewhere, but clicking on any of the lines does not take me to actual code:

[image]

Once I click the *play* "Continue Execution" button in the debug menu, the Simulator takes me to the device's home screen (away from app) and the following message is then displayed in the Application Output:

> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
>   a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
>   used by your application.

### File setup

I am not sure if this is common practice for Xamarin projects, but we actually have two `AppDelegate` files:

- AppDelegateIPad.cs
- AppDelegateIPhone.cs

Both classes here inherit the abstract class `UIApplicationDelegate` and both classes override the abstract class' `UIWindow` property.

The only places which references `AppDelegateIPad` and `AppDelegateIPhone` classes are the two *.xib* files:

- MainWindowIPad.xib
- MainWindowIPhone.xib

The thing is, our app **is working** in production and is currently in the app store. I just started on this project and am new with Xamarin. The original developer left the team some time ago. As this solution was working at one time, I assume the errors that I am experiencing have something to do with my using a newer version of Xcode than the original developer was using. However, all attempts to use a different version of Xcode or iOS SDK have not fixed the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will gladly provide any additional information you may need. Thanks!

### Edit - preview of delegate files:

#### AppDelegateIPad

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Mobile.iOS
{
    // The name AppDelegateIPad is referenced in the MainWindowIPad.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegateIPad : SDSApplicationDelegate
    {
        //Deleting this property will allow the debugger to run an iPhone
        public override UIWindow Window {
            get {
                return window;
            }
            set {
                window = value;
            }
        }

        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {...
```

#### AppDelegateIPhone

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Mobile.iOS
{
    // The name AppDelegateIPhone is referenced in the MainWindowIPhone.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegateIPhone : SDSApplicationDelegate
    {
        private SDSInitialLoadViewController _InitialLoadViewController;
        private SDSLoginTableViewController _LoginTableViewController;

        public SDSMainMenuTableViewController MainMenuTableViewController {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public override UIWindow Window {
            get {
                return window;
            }
            set {
                window = value;
            }
        }

        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {...
```

Comment: Are you able to post what is happening in both the two app delegates?

Comment: The debug never makes it to either files (I've placed breakpoints in many different places to try and find out). I included some relevant code from each file though. Let me know if you would like me to provide more info. Thanks @IainSmith!

Comment: These classes are partial so I assume there's an additional declaration somewhere (probably in a AppDelegateIPad.Designer.cs file), can you show that as well?

Comment: Thanks @RolfBjarneKvinge. There is actually no AppDelegateIPad.Designer.cs file. The only Designer.cs files are `MainWindowIPad.xib.designer.cs` and `MainWindowIPhone.xib.designer.cs`. Is there a particular declaration that you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, those, please (one is enough actually).